# Paystack: How to pass paystack options in angular4-paystack button

Tags: angular

I pass options from my controller.ts file:

```
this.options = {
            key: this.key,
            plan: response.responseData.plan_code,
            email: 'usertest@mailinator.com',
            amount: response.responseData.amount,
            ref: this.reference
        };
```

& in my controller.html file:

```
<button class="mt-3 btn-global blue-btn"
                angular4-paystack
                [paystackOptions]= "{{ options | json }}"
                (paymentInit)="paymentCancel()"
                (close)="paymentCancel()"
                (callback)="paymentDone($event)">Pay with Paystack
            </button>
```

It give me errors of template parsing (interpolation) but when I put following code

```
{{ options | json }}
```

it prints data as it is.

```
{ "key": "pk_test_myPublicKey", "plan": "PLN_0hmp3uju90o9rao", "email": "usertest@mailinator.com", "amount": "50000", "ref": "ref-34625380671166" }
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Just remove the brackets and json pipe. You shouldn't be passing in template syntax, just pass in the variable.

```
<button class="mt-3 btn-global blue-btn"
                angular4-paystack
                [paystackOptions]= "options"
                (paymentInit)="paymentCancel()"
                (close)="paymentCancel()"
                (callback)="paymentDone($event)">Pay with Paystack
            </button>
```